# Disabling app updates

Tags: applications, ipod-touch, ios-appstore, ios, auto-update

I have iOS 8.2 running on my iPod Touch (7); and since I downloaded iOS 8, all of my apps update automatically. I personally don't like that at all, I want to see what updates are available and what apps want to update before they do, not after.

Is there any way that I can disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings > iTunes & App Store > Automatic Downloads

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was easy... I thought I had already done that XD

Comment: OS update may have reset it. I have a feeling I thought I'd done it too...