# How to update apps in background?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

When an update is released I have to manually update apps.
How can I do to update apps in the background auomatically.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/180040/88313) for info on disabling automatic updates.  Just turn the updates on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings → iTunes & App Store and enable Automatic Downloads: Updates.

[image]